# Google cloud composer: tasks not executed in scheduled dag run, but executed successfully in manual dag run

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I have a [DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#dags) with multiple tasks. When the DAG is executed by scheduler it enters `running` state but none of tasks in the DAG has any status. However, if the same DAG is executed manually (`Trigger Dag` button click) - tasks become `queued->running->success`.
I have tried to check Stackdriver logs for "Cloud Composer Environment" - but haven't found any suspicious log entries. Also have checked task logs in airflow UI - they were empty.

Why are scheduled dag runs stuck? How can I figure out reasons of scheduled DAGs problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason was `start_date` param. It was calculated with this way:

```
START_DATE = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
dag = airflow.DAG(
        'data_transfer_dag',
        'catchup=False',
        default_args = {
            'owner': 'Zufar',
            'depends_on_past': False,
            'email': [''],
            'email_on_failure': False,
            'email_on_retry': False,
            'retries': 1,
            'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
            'start_date': START_DATE,
        },
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
)
```

Fix was to use hardcoded day: `START_DATE = datetime.datetime(2020,1,1)`. So it can't be calculated based on current time. Just use hardcoded past date.

Comment: You might want to use days_ago() from the Airflow utils for something like this.



`from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    'start_date': days_ago(0)
}`